# Ruby: undefined method 'unpack' when I'm trying to extract data between to regex markers in a hex file

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, unpack

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#this is the capture file from tcpdump for printer (9100) traffic
filename = 'cap.pcl'
capdata = {}

File.open(filename,"r") {|capdata| capdata.read}

#this is the regex that identifies the print job type as PCL or PJL
  if capdata.unpack("H*")[0] =~ /(1b45|1b25|1b26)/
    printjobtype = "PCL"
    print_good("Printjob of type PCL recieved")

  #trying to extract only the data between these 2 markers
    print_job_pcl = Array(pcdata.unpack("H*")[0].match(/((1b45|1b25|1b26).*(1b45|1b252d313233343558))/i)[0]).pack("H*")
  end
## error I'm receiving, 
## extractPrintJob.rb:8: undefined method `unpack' for #<File:cap.pcl (closed)> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: You must have transcribed something incorrectly.  This code will fail on the `capdata.unpack` reference, since hashes don't have an `unpack` method. Also, you're `File.open` method call doesn't do anything, since the block you're passing to it just throws away the results of reading the file.

Comment: I thought that the ("H*")[0] meant Hex? this is parsing a printer file which is hex. Basically, I'm trying to open cap.pcl (a binary blob) and match for the PJL start and end code and sstip out everything in between. I'm shockingly new to coding..